# Getting text from dropdown lists and using text to insert into Oracle database using Java GUI

Tags: java

I am creating a GUI where the user can select the text needed for inserting the appropriate values for a file into a database.

The user will browse for multiple files. Set certain dropdown list values on these files and then when pressing submit this will insert the file into a table called fileData and the values will be put into fileData3.

fileData has columns - file_id, data (This column is where the file is actually stored)

fileData3 has columns - file_id, name, col2, col3, col4

How can I get started? I have created the dropdown values I need I just need to know how to connect to the database and put the values chosen from the user into inserts when the user presses submit.

### Edit

```
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:test", "username",
                "password");
```

Comment: *"how to connect to the database java"* in a search engine shows as 2nd link - [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html).  Go for it.  (And start with a search engine, next time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a read through:

- [JDBC Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/)
- [How to use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)
- [`JComboBox` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html)

Try a few things and if you have any particular trouble, don't hesitate to post another question

In addition, take a look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), things like `JDialog`, `JTextField` and `JPasswordField` would all be worth looking into

Comment: I understand how to connect to the database I have edited the above, I need to know how the user can enter a username and password instead of defining one? Thanks

Comment: That's not even close to what the original question was asking

Comment: *"..not even close to what the original question was asking"*  Pfft..  Knowing what the question is, removes all the mystery from answering.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Since when did any of me questions actually answer the OP's question anyway ;)